# How to select the first value of a column of a data frame according to the group using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, pipe

I have 2 frames of data which I joined using the `left_join()` function. Then, I grouped the data by Group using the `group_by()` function. Using the `mutate()` function I want to create a column to repeatedly display the first value of column V2 according to the sort group.

In MWE the first value of `V2` for Group 1 is 5 and for Group 2 it is 7.5. However, the code I wrote for this is selecting the first value from column V2 and repeating for both groups without separating as I want.

**Note:** it is simple because it seems to copy column `V2` but this selection of the first value is necessary for me to do other calculations.

Any tips?

```
library(dplyr)

Group <- c(1, 2)
V1 <- c(10, 20, 30)
V2 <- c(5, 7.5)

df1 <- expand.grid(V1 = V1,
                   Group = Group) 

df2 <- data.frame(Group, V2)

df <- df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(first = first(.$V2))
```

| V1 | Group | V2 | first | The `first` column I want |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 5.0 | 5 | 5.0 |
| 20 | 1 | 5.0 | 5 | 5.0 |
| 30 | 1 | 5.0 | 5 | 5.0 |
| 10 | 2 | 7.5 | 5 | 7.5 |
| 20 | 2 | 7.5 | 5 | 7.5 |
| 30 | 2 | 7.5 | 5 | 7.5 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `.$` and it will work as `.$` get the entire column breaking the group attribute and thus the `first` will be the first row value of the entire column

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  left_join(df2) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(first = first(V2))
```